# How to access bottom canvas layer in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have such html:

```
<div id="main_window">
 <canvas id="canvas_hex_logic" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
 <canvas id="canvas_ground" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#canvas_hex_logic{
 position: absolute;
 top:31px;
 left:201px;
 z-index: 0;
}
 #canvas_ground{
 position: absolute;
 top:31px;
 left:201px;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

in #canvas_hex_logic I'm rendering mask for my hexagons:
[image: hex logic layer]

over it I'm placing ground layer:

[image]

part of JS code, for picking color under mouse:

```
  ..... mouse event handler above .....
  var c_hex = document.getElementById("canvas_hex_logic");
  var ctx_hex = c_hex.getContext("2d");
  ..... ..... ..... ..... ..... .....
  var color = ctx_hex.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1).data;
```

This code working, if #canvas_hex_logic is on tom of other layers.

So, question is - how to pick color under mouse from #canvas_hex_logic layer when it is overlayed with another layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
Acuallty, I've founded easiest way:

```
#canvas_ground {
left: 201px;
pointer-events: none;  <<--------- this helps
position: absolute;
top: 31px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the coordinates of your click in the canvas that's on top and find the color at the corresponding pixel in the canvas that's below.

Click events have data associated to them that contains the coordinates of the click.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click). Or rather, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.layerX) for even greater detail!